# Store timestamp value in SQL Database

Tags: mysql

What is actually stored in Timestamp field in the SQL?

My requirement is to only store the time value like 07:00 PM

And the thing when I store only time value I see error message like

```
Incorrect datetime value: '07:00 PM' for column 'MY_TIME' at row 1
```

I also tried giving 07:00:00 , but it too returns same.

And when I pass entire date, it accepts.

Is there any way to only give time to timestamp field or date is required there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timestamp contains both date and time. For time only try [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) column type.

Answer (score 2):

Timestamp is a date with time. It's the usual name for the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT.

If you only want to store the time, you should use a column with [time type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/time.html) (assuming you are using MySQL, may vary depending on the DB engine you use).